# Node js - puppeteer page per proxy plugin - proxy connection error

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

The picture to do when trying for the puppeteer Page proxy plugin.

ERROR_FAIL

No solution or error found for now.

Other proxy types are http,https,sock5,sock5 validation

Chrome is running as an argument there is no problem in my car
but i need to use it because it wants to proxy to its page

https://www.hizliresim.com/qtb4ja1

Basically, these plugins send to other request classes on the page, so they are provided with a proxy for transportation purposes.

Others on Github threads are complaining about the same error but no solution has been shared

I don't understand how other plugins do the same thing.

Comment: Please, replace the iamge with the actual log text.

Comment: I couldn't find any log text